# Как удалить namespace только в атрибуте тега?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

Мне надо чтобы внутри `xml` один атрибут внутри тега был без префикса `xsi:` и для этого я нарыл решение использовать `xslt`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

отрабатывает хорошо, даже слишком после процедуры необходимые атрибуты без префикса И без содержимого. Почему то обрезается как префикс, так и содержимое, остается только пустой атрибут, например надо удалить префикс у `type`:

```
 <out:Declarant xsi:type="out:RequestAccount">
```

ожидалось что будет так:

```
 <out:Declarant type="out:RequestAccount">
```

а получается так:

```
 <out:Declarant type="">
```

я не понимаю почему удаляется содержимое?

**ПРИМЕР XML**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<out:CoordinateMessage xmlns:out="http://asguf.mos.ru/rkis_gu/coordinate/v6/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <out:CoordinateDataMessage>
      <out:Service>
         <out:RegNum>136609845</out:RegNum>
         <out:RegDate>2018-08-02T11:10:23+03:00</out:RegDate>
         <out:ServiceNumber>0001-9000003-0</out:ServiceNumber>
         <out:ServicePrice xsi:nil="true"/>
         <out:PrepareTargetDate xsi:nil="true"/>
         <out:OutputTargetDate xsi:nil="true"/>
         <out:Responsible>
            <out:LastName>оператор </out:LastName>
            <out:FirstName>оператор </out:FirstName>
            <out:MiddleName>оператор </out:MiddleName>
            <out:JobTitle>оператор Портала</out:JobTitle>
            <out:Phone>+7 (495) 5/out:Phone>
            <out:Email>cpgu</out:Email>
         </out:Responsible>
         <out:Department>
            <out:Name>Департамент информационных</out:Name>
            <out:Code>2043</out:Code>
            <out:Inn>70</out:Inn>
            <out:Ogrn>943347</out:Ogrn>
            <out:RegDate>2010:00:00</out:RegDate>
            <out:SystemCode>9003</out:SystemCode>
         </out:Department>
         <out:CreatedByDepartment>
            <out:Name>ПУ</out:Name>
            <out:Code>1</out:Code>
            <out:Inn>7710878000</out:Inn>
            <out:Ogrn>1107746943347</out:Ogrn>
            <out:RegDate>2009-11-18T00:00:00</out:RegDate>
            <out:SystemCode>1</out:SystemCode>
         </out:CreatedByDepartment>
         <out:PrepareFactDate>2018-08-</out:PrepareFactDate>
         <out:OutputFactDate xsi:nil="true"/>
      </out:Service>
      <out:SignService Id="ea946206033c1e">
         <out:ServiceTypeCode>0201</out:ServiceTypeCode>
         <out:Copies>1</out:Copies>
         <out:Declarant xsi:type="out:RequestAccount">
            <out:FullName>Общество с ограниченной ответств</out:FullName>
            <out:Name>ООО "ДК</out:Name>
            <out:Ogrn>113772249</out:Ogrn>
            <out:OgrnDate xsi:nil="true"/>
            <out:Inn>74053</out:Inn>
            <out:InnDate xsi:nil="true"/>
            <out:PostalAddress/>
            <out:FactAddress/>
            <out:Phone>(916) 77</out:Phone>
            <out:EMail>v@pioneer.ru</out:EMail>
         </out:Declarant>
</out:SignService>
```

Comment: Добавте пример XML файла, который вы трансформируете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечаю адаптированным [ответом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5875074/1892060) коллеги с англоязычного сайта:

```xslt
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```